# AWS Lambda and Promises: Callbacks not being called

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, aws-lambda

I'm assuming that I'm lacking some fundamentals on promises. I have a process that is within a AWS Lambda that downloads three files, then produces an output that is sent via email.

```
module.exports.test = async (event) => {
   var p = download1();
   var c = download2();
   var h = download3();

   await Promise.all([p, c, h]).then(() => {
     ... bunch of logic manipulating the data
     customers.forEach(i => {
       buildFile().then(data => {
         sendEmail(data).then(response => {
            console.log('Email sent successfully');
         });
       });
     });
   }, errHandler);
};
```

Both the buildFile and sendEmail functions return a Promise, but I never get to the 'Email sent successfully' message. It runs the code, but never actually returns before the Lambda completes (at least that's what I think is happening).

My understanding was that the Promise would fulfill the callback, but now I'm thinking I need to do something similar to how I did the downloads within the original Promise.all(). Is that the right direction?

The process should get the files, then it loops through customers to create each file and send via SES.

Comment: what if you try it without `await`

Comment: `customers.forEach` iterates the customers and for each one it creates a promise but you don't wait for it to be fulfilled. Save these promises into an array and run `Promise.all` and them and wait till they're done.

Comment: As @alfasin pointed out, you are racing. But, in addition, you should use `.catch()` for EACH promise chain so that you can catch errors that may be created within the chain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for

```
module.exports.test = async (event) => {
  var p = download1();
  var c = download2();
  var h = download3();

  try {
    await Promise.all([p, c, h]);

    // ... bunch of logic manipulating the data
    var promises = customers.map(async (i) => {
      var data = await buildFile();
      var response = await sendEmail(data);
      console.log('Email sent successfully');
    });
    await Promise.all(promises);
  } catch(e) {
    errHandler(e);
  }
};
```

Your `test` function didn't wait for the promises that you created in the `forEach` loop, so the lambda completes before everything is done.

Answer (score 1):

@Bergi answer is correct, however I would like to expand it a little bit and give you some resources to increase or strength your `Promises` knowledge. I'll use the next snippet of code, it's a bit cumbersome because I wrote it on `Google Chrome` snippets so feel free to paste it there and play around with it:

```
(function() {
    const promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve('Replicant');
        }, 300);
    });

    const promise2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve('Human?');
        }, 300);
    });

    function buildFile(type) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(`${type}`);
            }, 300);
        });
    }

    function sendMail(customer, answer) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(`Sent test to: ${customer}, he/she is a ${answer}`);
            }, 300);
        });
    }

    let customers = ['Rob Batty', 'Rachel', 'Deckard'];

    async function myFunc() {

        const [a, b, c] = await Promise.all([promise1, promise1, promise2]);
        const answers = [a, b, c];

//         const promises = customers.map(async (name, index) => {
//             const file = await buildFile(answers[index]);
//             const mail = await sendMail(name, file);
//             console.log(mail);
//         });

        const promises = customers.map((name, index) => {
            buildFile(answers[index])
                .then(file => sendMail(name, file))
                .then(sent => console.log(sent))
                // If you're going to use Promises this is important! :D
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
        });

        const [m1, m2, m3] = await Promise.all(promises);

        console.log(m1, m2, m3);
    }

    myFunc();
})()
```

As pointed out in the answer, the problem is related to the use of `forEach`, why? Well, simply because you're executing `asynchronous` code on a `synchronous` type of method, the don't get along very well :), so, the solution is to create an `Array` of `Promises`, like a `Factory`. After the `map` function the `Promises` are `Pending` nor `Fullfiled` or `Rejected` it's when you call the `Promise.all()` method that you await for their results and they give you the values or in your use case, generate the file and then send the email to the user. I hope this helps you to get a better understanding on how `Promises` works. I'll leave at the end two very important links, at least for me, that helped me out at some point with `Promises`. Cheers, sigfried.

- [Nolans Lawson's Article](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html)
- [MDN Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Promises are not "executed" at all. Promises are objects that represent an asynchronous result, nothing more nothing less. After the `map` call, the tasks that you started are already running and the promises are all pending. You're not gonna "execute" them with `Promise.all`, you can just wait for them.

Comment: Thank you @Bergi, I'll fix the answer and now thanks to your comment it's all crystal clear. Cheers, sigfried.